# Manipulate HTML page via PHP

Tags: php, head, inject

Hello I have INCLUDED a PHP file in the end of an HTML page. Now I want to add a style file before the end of the tag HEAD. But I need to do this via this php file, I have no choice.

I have and `index.php` file and at the end of this file I am loading `script.php`
I need to add a script in the header of index page using the `script.php`

**Folder structure:**

- index.php
- script.php

**The `index.php` file have this code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 something
</head>

<body>
   something
</body>
</html>
<?php 
   include "script.php"
?>
```

How can I put something in the head of the HTML/PHP when I have the script.php file at the end of a page.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: I am improving it...1 sec :)

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're doing and what you're asking? Does this index.php/script.php file produce the full HTML page, and you want to stick some more stuff into the <head> section of the page? If the <head> section is all HTML, you can stick `<?php include 'script.php'; ?>` at the appropriate point. I'm assuming that script.php writes out something and is not simply a function definition.

Comment: @PhilPerry sure, is a hard question... can you check it now.

Comment: I'll ask the obvious. Why can't you just move the include into the head?

Comment: That is the PROBLEM the script file is loaded at the end of each page and I need to put something in the header without moving the script.php position.

Comment: So, make a new include file and include it.

Comment: That is way I need help because I cannot move, that is the challenge. That is the difficult.

Comment: WHY can't you move it? It seems like a structural problem you're trying to band-aid

Comment: @relentless please check Mark answer is something like that that I need. That challenge is manipulate the DOM via PHP

Comment: Yes, that solution might work, but again, WHY can't you move it. Fix the real problem.

Comment: I am going to change 40000 pages. I don't want to do that manually :)

Comment: OK, so currently you have script.php which adds whatever it adds to the end of the page, after </html>. If it can't be moved to the <head>, make a new script2.php and `<?php include 'script2.php' ?>` at the appropriate place. You're not manipulating the DOM at this level; you're adding source code.

Comment: 40000 pages need updating? Is the change needed consistent enough that you could write a script (e.g., in Perl) to automate the update? And you haven't explained _why_ you can't just update script.php rather than hitting the PHP source code. Are you just defining Javascript functions in script.php, or doing some other things?

Comment: Yes... I tried for last 4 hours to do that. I cannot make my Perl code work with my server :(

Comment: A simple find and replace would do the trick too.

Comment: @relentless every page in dynamic generated :)

Comment: Then why would you have to manually update them?

Comment: @PhilPerry here is the main problem -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940239/run-a-perl-script-in-plesk-11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this. I can think about 2 nasty workarounds for your problem though:

1. If the script has buffering activated (called ob_start somewhere before HEAD was closed), you could get it as a string and clean it wirh ob_get_clean, then insert your code and ECHO it again. Could look like this:

   ```
   <?php
   $output = ob_get_clean();
   $output = substr_replace($output, $your_code, strpos($output, '</head>'), 0);
   echo $output;
   ?>
   ```
2. Since modern browsers are quite forgiving, you actually can put style tags after the closing html and they will still work. I woudln't do this though, since it's bad habit

Answer (score 0):

Create IF logic within your included PHP page, and then include it into both the HEAD and at the end of your HTML.

Within your HTML, set a variable before the HEAD's include, and then reset the same variable after the HEAD's include.

Regarding the IF logic, set it up so TRUE only runs the style sheet, and FALSE skips over the style sheet and runs the rest of the PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is this:

- put ob_start(); at the start of your page or all pages.. ( i hope for you this is possible)
- use ob_get_contents(); to get all the contents into a variable:
- inject your code with a replace
- clean the output buffer with ob_end_clean()
- echo the modified code.

so this code will look like this:

```
<?php ob_start();
//a lot of your code and html here
$codeToInject="yourcode";
$content=ob_get_contents();
$content=str_replace("</head>",$codeToInject."</head>");
ob_end_clean();
echo $content;
?>
```

But be aware.. this is NOT the way to go. It will potentially slow down your page. Its not a clean way of coding, actually its tricking around. if possible you should reconcider refactoring your code in a way this is not needed.

Comment: I will try it now. Something like this is what I need. I can prepend and append so I can try it :)