# Run a Perl script in PHP - Plesk 11

Tags: perl, plesk

How can I run a a Perl script in every page of the server?

I put the code at `/var/www/cgi-bin`, now I need the correct the code to run it. Where should I place it.

I have added this code to the httpd.conf:

- Action add-footer /cgi-bin/script.cgi
- AddHandler add-footer .htm .htm

and on the site I have added the code script.

If the page is .html the code runs but is the page is PHP the code does not run.

I have tried this but is does not work, in works on HTML files but not in PHP

```
<Directory / >
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
  AddHandler php-cgi .php 
  AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl
  AddHandler cgi-script .html
  AddHandler cgi-script .php

  Action add-footer /cgi-bin/script.cgi 
  AddHandler add-footer .html .htm .php php
</Directory>
```

Comment: what do you mean? i dont understand your question

Comment: okay, if i understand you correct, you want to add a `Php`-Footer on every delivered page? I just would like to know, why? - i think you should re-think what you need. you could create a template file for example and fill that template file with Perl. For example [Template::Toolkit](http://p3rl.org/Template::Toolkit)

Comment: I manage to get it work with HTML now I need to make it work on PHP files.

Comment: something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049104/include-footer-page-to-any-page-in-the-server ??

Comment: Yes but I need in the entire SERVER.

Comment: you can put it in the appropriate virtualhost directive in the Apache configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I was trying does not work with Dynamic Content it only work with Static Content.